# Confusion in DefaultHelper class in android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

When are the startElement characters StopElement methods called in the DefaultHelper class of in android?

The package name of the class is
org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler

Answer (score 1):

```
<pussy> cat </pussy>
```

When the xml parser comes across the tag `<pussy>` , startElement() is called
and when the parser detects `</pussy>` stopElement() is called.

The function characters() is called with the data "`cat`"

Comment: I figured that even after encountering </pussy> , the method character is called. I found this out by tracing the program.So you got to make sure that when the character method is called for the second time it does nothing. I achieved this by using a boolean flag.

Answer (score 0):

`I figured that even after encountering </pussy> , the method character is called.`

The `characters()` method is most probably called the second time (after `stopElement()`) because there is a whitespace (e.g. newline) character after `</pussy>`.

Try putting your test XML all on one line to see if it makes any change.

Comment: i can't change the xml, it comes from a server.

Comment: Then convert `char[]` to `String` and do `string.trim()` to get rid of all heading/trailing whitespaces.

Comment: tried it, does not work. but how will it? how does that help. if i remove the white spaces from after the end tag, it stil does not change it in the original xml. next time i parse , i will still encounter the same problem.

Comment: It helps by detecting an empty line (string.equals("") after trim()) and ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<element>
  This is character. or may be another elements and it's character.
</element>
```

startElement(..) will be called when any new xml tag get start like  and
endElement(..) will be called when an element is ended